# how do we know which event fired load event in extjs 4.1 store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

I am using extjs 4.1 store. Which looks like this:

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['myModel'],
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/aaa/bbb',
        timeout: '90000',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'beforeload': function (store, options) {
            },
        'load': function (store, options) {

        }
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'SortOrder',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});
```

initially I am loading data through proxy. Later based on user interaction, I will extract the data from the store usign `store.proxy.reader.rawData` and store it in some variable.

Then at later stage, I will load into the store from the variable using  `loadRawData()`.

When [loadRawData()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-loadRawData) is called, it also fires the load event.

**What I want:** I want to diffrentiate between load event fired due to proxy loading the data for the first time vs load event fired due to loadRawData().

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to ExtJS version 5.1 allows you access to store.loadCount which will let you to check whether this is the first load or a subsequent load. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-loadCount

If you don't want to upgrade, you could manually implement this feature (e.g. increment a custom variable on your store in the 'load' listener) and check it to see which behaviour you want to perform.